# how to listen to UDP broadcast?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some server that using UDP broadcast to send information to my application.
I know that the server send his information to ip address 225.225.1.5 port 8811 
But i don't know how to listen to this.

any help please ...

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [How to join source specific multicast group in C# (IGMPv3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145804/how-to-join-source-specific-multicast-group-in-c-sharp-igmpv3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your server platform? There are php, perl, sh and I'm sure c#/.net code that can listen.

You can use the

```
netcat -ul 8811
```

command to listen to the UDP dump

On windows you can try:

```
netstat -an | find "UDP" | more
```

you might get an output like this:

```
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1234           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1235           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1236           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1237           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1238           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1239           *:*
```

feel free to grep the port

Running:

```
netstat -a -p UDP -b
```

can be helpful in determining what is attached to those ports.

This is really helpful: 
http://bansky.net/echotool/

For server mode listening on UDP port 8811 run following command

```
C:\EchoTool> echotool /p udp /s 8811
```